# Proving the difference between upper and lower Darboux sums and the integral is less than the oscillation

Tags: calculus

I have the following question, I'm stuck on:
Let $f$ be Riemann integradable on $[a,b]$ then prove that:
1. $|U(P,f) - \int_a^b{f(x)}dx|\leq\Omega(P,f)$
2. $|L(P,f) - \int_a^b{f(x)}dx|\leq\Omega(P,f)$

Where $U$,$L$ are the Darboux upper and lower sums, and $\Omega$ is the oscillation of $f$ relative to partition $P$

I would appreciate any hints or directions since I'm stuck.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) \le \Omega(f,P)$ and
$U(f,P) \ge \int f \ge L(f,P)$.